# Making group video call application wrtc vs mediasoup

Tags: node.js, webrtc, mediasoup

I am making a group video call nodejs application.

I come to know about two npm packages

1. wrtc - from this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GMbdEnK8h3U
2. mediasoup

the mediasoup is very large 167 mb (https://www.npmjs.com/package/mediasoup) compared to wrtc 82kb (https://www.npmjs.com/package/wrtc).

I want to know why there is such a large difference which is better suitable for the purpose of developing a group meeting webapp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.wrtc** is a node package which enables you to make mostly **one to many** media stream, in a sense of broadcasting. its a wrapper on top of simply webrtc framework
in a case its one producer of stream and others participants of a call are just listener since their stream are not transmitted back.

**2.mediasoup** is a library which uses analogy of transports to manage any kind of topology of call you wish from one to many, few to many even many to many which you can call video conference on this call

if peer wants to produce media to be received by other peers then he create a **producer** from his transport
if peer wants to receive from other peer on the conference he create **consumer** from the transport.

with all the benefits of mediasoup, the downside is, it have a learning curve with just few tutorials on youtube

Comment: in your case a meeting, i think you need mediasoup

Answer (score 0):

I am going for wrtc and having custom logic to manage rooms. Going to try doing a poc with it since mediasoup seems like so much overhead. It's like learning kafka and other message queues, sometimes just unnecessary.

Comment: i totally agree with you, but which path to choose always dictated by the project requirements...